# What can I do to ensure my pool doesn't freeze?

Tags: plumbing, pool, freezing

I live about 8 miles north of the Gulf of Mexico. It will be in the low teens (below freezing) in the morning. It will be record setting, so I'm not sure what to expect. The pump and equipment is in a heated room however I don't know what the temps could do to the pool and everything outside. It hit 32 F at 7:30 pm.

What can I do to prevent damage to the pool, pipes and pump?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Do I need to do anything to protect my pool during a rare freeze?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/3484/2196)

Comment: So, what does it look like this morning?

Comment: The pool will be fine.  Water has to give up a whole lot of energy to freeze.  What might freeze is any above ground pipes near the pump.  Just keep the pump running while the temperature is cool.

Answer (score 4):

Run the pump. If you have a pool cover, put it on.

The pool itself stores a lot of heat.

Moving water is much harder to freeze than water standing still.

Comment: Thank you. We have a screen enclosure, no cover. We never needed one here before. Thanks again.